# merge to results from the same table using union

Tags: mysql

here guys i found the year which has the most games and list games but coudn't show them together so i used order by clause to make it in the first row then used the limit to only show it,i did that twice to one for the max and one for the min each works fine seperatly but when using union to gather the two rows it gives me erreur any help ?

```
select * from(
select  year,number_of_countries from (
    select year,max(countt) over(partition by year) as number_of_countries from (
        select year,noc,row_number() over(partition by year order by noc) as countt from (  
            select year,noc from athlete_events2
            group by year,noc
            order by year,noc ) t
            order by year)s)d
            group by number_of_countries,year
            order by number_of_countries)q
limit 1;
union
select * from(
select  year,number_of_countries from (
    select year,max(countt) over(partition by year) as number_of_countries from (
        select year,noc,row_number() over(partition by year order by noc) as countt from (  
            select year,noc from athlete_events2
            group by year,noc
            order by year,noc ) t
            order by year)s)d
            group by number_of_countries,year
            order by number_of_countries desc
            )q
limit 1;
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from end of the first query and add parentheses qround the queries as you have `LIMIT` in the queries.

```
(select * from(
select  year,number_of_countries from (
    select year,max(countt) over(partition by year) as number_of_countries from (
        select year,noc,row_number() over(partition by year order by noc) as countt from (  
            select year,noc from athlete_events2
            group by year,noc
            order by year,noc ) t
            order by year)s)d
            group by number_of_countries,year
            order by number_of_countries)q
limit 1
)
union
(select * from(
select  year,number_of_countries from (
    select year,max(countt) over(partition by year) as number_of_countries from (
        select year,noc,row_number() over(partition by year order by noc) as countt from (  
            select year,noc from athlete_events2
            group by year,noc
            order by year,noc ) t
            order by year)s)d
            group by number_of_countries,year
            order by number_of_countries desc
            )q
limit 1
);
```

Comment: So its a TYPO, we dont answer typo's as they are almost never going to be any use to others. We make a comment (basically this is a comment) and close the question as a typo

Comment: @RiggsFolly completed the answer